# Mysql Join Query Dilemma

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 4 tables and I am trying to extract certain data in one, this query might not be really well structured but i need atleast something for my prototype. I got

```
    users
    ------
    id
    parent_id
    name
    surname

    bookings
    --------
    id
    client_id
    division_id
    subdivision_id
    sub_event_id
    host_id
    guest_id

    itineraries
    ----------
    id
    booking_id
    itinerary_type_id
    client_cost

    itinerary_type
    -------------
    flight
    hotel
    transfer
```

Here is my current query

```
    

         SELECT 

         (SELECT CONCAT(name,' ',surname) FROM users WHERE id = bookings.host_id) AS host, 
    CONCAT(users.name,'  ',users.surname) AS name, 
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 1 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) AS flight,
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 2 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) AS hotel,
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 3 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL)  AS transfer,
    (total1 + total2 + total3)  AS total

    FROM 

    (SELECT(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 1 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) as total1,
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 2 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) as total2,
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 3 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) as total3 FROM  bookings) q, users 

    JOIN bookings ON bookings.guest_id = users.id 
    JOIN clients ON users.client_id = bookings.client_id 
    JOIN details ON details.user_id = users.id 
    JOIN divisions ON divisions.client_id = users.client_id 
    JOIN subdivisions ON subdivisions.division_id = bookings.division_id JOIN sub_events ON sub_events.id = bookings.sub_event_id 
    JOIN itineraries ON itineraries.booking_id = bookings.id WHERE bookings.id = 1572 
    GROUP BY bookings.id
```

expected result is

```
    host       |name      |flight|hotel|transfer|Total
    --------------------------------------------------
    Mike Little|Bob Parker|200   |100  |30      |330
```

At the moment I am using subquery to temporary make a table from where i am getting the total.. but it doesn't seem to work... i reckon, problem is i can't pass the booking id to the new temp subquery table.... any more ways to work around it? i will be eternally great ful! :-) .. really !!!

Comment: `SUM(client_cost)` in the second set of subqueries?

Comment: My question still holds: are your tables properly indexed? If not, the query may take *very long*. See [How MySQL uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the exact SQL you are looking for (omitted a lot of joins to other code tables but included only the major query) and there could be silly syntax errors as I have not tested it. But the idea is to select a summary for the bookings, then join the summary with user table. (The query is generalized to accommodate multiple booking ID selection.)

```
SELECT
    booking_summary.booking_id,
    booking_summary.host_id,
    concat(users.name, ' ', users.surname) as host, 
    concat(users.name, ' ', users.surname) as name, 
    booking_summary.flight, 
    booking_summary.hotel, 
    booking_summary.transfer, 
    (booking_summary.flight+booking_summary.hotel+booking_summary.transfer) as total
FROM
    (select booking_id, max(host_id) as host_id, sum(flight) as flight, sum(hotel) as hotel, sum(transfer) as transfer from (
        select b.host_id, i.booking_id, i.client_cost as flight, 0 as hotel, 0 as transfer from itineraries i, bookings b where i.itinerary_type_id = 1 AND i.booking_id in (1572, 1573, 1574) and i.booking_id=b.id
        union all
        select b.host_id, i.booking_id, 0 as flight, i.client_cost as hotel, 0 as transfer from itineraries i, bookings b where i.itinerary_type_id = 2 AND i.booking_id in (1572, 1573, 1574) and i.booking_id=b.id
        union all
        select b.host_id, i.booking_id, 0 as flight, 0 as hotel, i.client_cost as transfer from itineraries i, bookings b where i.itinerary_type_id = 3 AND i.booking_id in (1572, 1573, 1574) and i.booking_id=b.id
    ) temp_booking_result group by booking_id) booking_summary,
    users
WHERE
    users.id=booking_summary.host_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Ronald.. that helped a lot.. just wanted to ask if there is not just one particular field value i.e. in this case 1572 ... how am i gonna transfer the value to the subqueries below??

Comment: @user1773018, please see the modified query and see if that is what you are looking for.